# How to sort a map on one of the attributes using a separate sort list as input in groovy?

Tags: groovy

How to sort a map based on key using a separate sort list as input in groovy? The sort list is dynamic and can change for every API call.

```
"preference": [81224, 40281, 30452, 30003, 44291, 32818],
"orders": {
    "30452": {
        "id": "l0089",
        "program": "ll",
        "tier": "2"
    },
    "40281": {
        "id": "88ds1",
        "program": "alm",
        "tier": "1"
    },
    "81224": {
        "id": "a0d0001",
        "program": "ccc",
        "tier": "4"
    },
    "32818": {
        "id": "a1212",
        "program": "alm",
        "tier": "4"
    },
    "44291": {
        "id": "37000",
        "program": "acm",
        "tier": "5"
    },
    "30003": {
        "id": "a1421",
        "program": "cld",
        "tier": "2"
    }
}
```

I tried something like this orders.sort{ preference.contains(it) as Comparator}

Answer (score 0):

A simple `indexOf` would do:

```
import groovy.json.*

// preparation
def str = '{"preference": [81224, 40281, 30452, 30003, 44291, 32818], "orders": {     "30452": {         "id": "l0089",         "program": "ll",         "tier": "2"     },     "40281": {         "id": "88ds1",         "program": "alm",         "tier": "1"     },     "81224": {         "id": "a0d0001",         "program": "ccc",         "tier": "4"     },     "32818": {         "id": "a1212",         "program": "alm",         "tier": "4"     },     "44291": {         "id": "37000",         "program": "acm",         "tier": "5"     },     "30003": {         "id": "a1421",         "program": "cld",         "tier": "2"     } } }'

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText str

// actual code
def preference = json.preference*.toString()
def orders = json.orders.sort{ preference.indexOf it.key }

// test
assert orders.toString() == '[81224:[id:a0d0001, program:ccc, tier:4], 40281:[id:88ds1, program:alm, tier:1], 30452:[id:l0089, program:ll, tier:2], 30003:[id:a1421, program:cld, tier:2], 44291:[id:37000, program:acm, tier:5], 32818:[id:a1212, program:alm, tier:4]]'

assert orders.keySet().asList() == preference
```